# Passing an object to a COM method

Tags: c#, com

I have an api for a third-party app I'm working with. In the api, they say the input parameter of type "VARIANTARG" needs to be passed in.

So I found this online, for using VARIANTARG in C#:
http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Structures/VARIANTARG.html

Here is my question. There are two properties in this VARIANTARG object which I'm not sure how to set:

```
public unsafe ushort* bstrVal;
public unsafe ushort** pbstrVal; // Note the double pointer on this one
```

Here is what I tried:

```
VARIANTARG v = new VARIANTARG();

//---------------------------------
//??? What goes here??? ???
string myString = "aaa";
v.bstrVal = &myString;
//  public unsafe ushort* bstrVal;
//??? and here:
v.pbstrVal = "???";
//  public unsafe ushort** pbstrVal;
//---------------------------------

MyCOMObj_App.SendTag(v);
```

Can you tell me how I'm supposed to set these two properties to some string value, and how to pass that to the COM Method?

Just for your reference....here is the VARIANTARG struct definition:

```
StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Size=16)]
struct VARIANTARG {
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public ushort vt;

    [FieldOffset(2)]
    public ushort wReserved1;

    [FieldOffset(4)]
    public ushort wReserved2;

    [FieldOffset(6)]
    public ushort wReserved3;

    [FieldOffset(8)]
    public long llVal;

    [FieldOffset(8)]
    public int lVal;

    [FieldOffset(8)]
    public byte bVal;

    [FieldOffset(8)]
    public short iVal;

    [FieldOffset(8)]
    public float fltVal;

    [FieldOffset(8)]
    public double dblVal;

    [FieldOffset(8)]
    public short boolVal;

    [FieldOffset(8)]
    public int scode;

    //[FieldOffset(8)]
    //public CY cyVal;

    [FieldOffset(8)]
    public double date;

    [FieldOffset(8)]
    public unsafe ushort* bstrVal;

    //[FieldOffset(8)]
    //public unsafe IUnknown* punkVal;

    //[FieldOffset(8)]
    //public unsafe IDispatch* pdispVal;

    //[FieldOffset(8)]
    //public unsafe SAFEARRAY* parray;

    [FieldOffset(8)]
    public unsafe byte* pbVal;

    [FieldOffset(8)]
    public unsafe short* piVal;

    [FieldOffset(8)]
    public unsafe int* plVal;

    [FieldOffset(8)]
    public unsafe long* pllVal;

    [FieldOffset(8)]
    public unsafe float* pfltVal;

    [FieldOffset(8)]
    public unsafe double* pdblVal;

    [FieldOffset(8)]
    public unsafe short* pboolVal;

    [FieldOffset(8)]
    public unsafe int* pscode;

    //[FieldOffset(8)]
    //public unsafe CY* pcyVal;

    [FieldOffset(8)]
    public unsafe double* pdate;

    [FieldOffset(8)]
    public unsafe ushort** pbstrVal;

    //[FieldOffset(8)]
    //public unsafe IUnknown** ppunkVal;

    //[FieldOffset(8)]
    //public unsafe IDispatch** ppdispVal;

    //[FieldOffset(8)]
    //public unsafe SAFEARRAY** pparray;

    [FieldOffset(8)]
    public unsafe VARIANTARG* pvarVal;

    [FieldOffset(8)]
    public unsafe void* byref;

    [FieldOffset(8)]
    public sbyte cVal;

    [FieldOffset(8)]
    public ushort uiVal;

    [FieldOffset(8)]
    public uint ulVal;

    [FieldOffset(8)]
    public ulong ullVal;

    [FieldOffset(8)]
    public int intVal;

    [FieldOffset(8)]
    public uint uintVal;

    //[FieldOffset(8)]
    //public unsafe DECIMAL* pdecVal;

    [FieldOffset(8)]
    public unsafe sbyte* pcVal;

    [FieldOffset(8)]
    public unsafe ushort* puiVal;

    [FieldOffset(8)]
    public unsafe uint* pulVal;

    [FieldOffset(8)]
    public unsafe ulong* pullVal;

    [FieldOffset(8)]
    public unsafe int* pintVal;

    [FieldOffset(8)]
    public unsafe uint* puintVal;

    [FieldOffset(8)]
    public unsafe void* pvRecord;

    //[FieldOffset(12)]
    //public unsafe IRecordInfo* pRecInfo;

    //[FieldOffset(0)]
    //public DECIMAL decVal;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The structure represents a Variant, which is here implemented as a C++ union. There are a lot of fields that overlap, such as the bool, float, long, etc. You don't need to set all fields, you only need to set one field and the type.
See, for instance: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms891678.aspx
Which one depends on which function you call; it should tell you what types of input it expects.